# How to draw a normal distribution with only integer values within a set range

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I am trying to draw a normal distribution with only integers within a range. I tried reading other posts here in stackoverflow, although some are somewhat related, I still can't find the answer. I would like to draw a normal distribution, like the rnorm function in which you can set the number of observations, mean, and standard deviation. However the distribution must be within 0:10 with only integers numbers. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Oh, yeah! that was simple enough. Thank you!

Comment: They won't be in a set range though. You could use something like `sample(0:10, prob = dnorm(0:10, mean = 5, sd = 2), size = 100, replace = TRUE)`.

Comment: You are right. I think this is better because I can make sure no value is extrapolating the set range. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean an actual normal distribution or just something that looks like a bell shape? Because, among other things, normal distributions are continuous.

Comment: I was just plotting the distribution, and I realized it doesn't look like a normal distribution. I was trying to solve a problem, I am trying to calculate the agreement score which is a measure of dispersion for discrete responses, and at the same time plot a normal distribution for illustration. Not sure how I am going to solve this now.

Comment: Looks like an xy problem to me

Comment: If the standard deviation is large enough, `rnorm(n, mean, sd) |> round(digits = 0) |> hist()` looks bell shaped enough for me

Comment: I am going to rethink how to present my idea, I wanted to give illustrations that matches my data, which uses discrete values. Maybe it won't be possible, I'm going to put some thought into it. Either way, I really appreciate the responses, and I've learned something new.

Comment: It sounds like it may not be infinite, so you could use GuedesBF's code using the truncated-normal, such as from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/truncnorm/

Comment: 2 days after the post, and I am actually using your suggestion. Truncated distribution with GuedesBF code. Thank you r2Evans.